# Proof of the Eberlein-Grothendick theorem

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, compactness

Let $C_p (K)$ be the space of all real continuous functions on a compact topological space $K$ endowed with the restriction of the topology $\mathcal{T}_p$ on $\mathbb{R}^{K}$ of the pointwise convergence on $K$.

Let $M$ be a nonempty relatively countably compact subset of $C_p (K)$.

I've checked that $\{\,f(k) : f \in M \} \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ is bounded for every $k \in K$ (I used the relatively countably compactness of $M$ here).

However, the textbook(Banach Space Theory, Fabian) says that $\overline{M}^{\mathbb{R}^K}$ is compact in $(\mathbb{R}^{K}, \mathcal{T}_p)$ by Tychonoff's theorem.

I'm stuck at this part!

How can I apply the Tychonoff theorem to conclude that $\overline{M}^{\mathbb{R}^K}$ is compact in $(\mathbb{R}^{K}, \mathcal{T}_p)$?

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Let $F_k = \overline{\{ f(k) : f \in M\}}$. What do you know about $$\prod_{k \in K} F_k\;?$$

Comment: @DanielFischer $F_k \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ is compact, so $\prod_{k \in K} \, F_k \subseteq \mathbb{R}^{K}$ is compact by Tychonoff's theorem.

Comment: Right. And can you see any relation between that product and $M$?

Comment: @DanielFischer You mean the $\mathbb{R}^{K}$-closure of $M$?

Comment: I meant $M$ itself (viewed as a subset of $\mathbb{R}^K$). I think it's simpler to look at that first. But if you can say the right thing about the $\mathbb{R}^K$-closure of $M$ directly, that works too of course.

Comment: @DanielFischer I see. For $f \in M$, $f(k) \in K$ for every $k \in K$. Thus the map $$f \mapsto (f(k))_{k \in K}$$ 
implies that $M \subseteq \prod_{k\in K} F_k$; hence $\overline{M}^{\mathbb{R}^{K}} \subseteq \prod_{k\in K} F_k$ since this product is closed. On the other hand, since this product is compact, $\overline{M}^{\mathbb{R}^K}$ is also compact. Thanks!

Comment: Would you like to convert that into an answer, or should I?

Comment: @DanielFischer In either case, that would be fine. You can do like that, as you feel comfortable.

Comment: Compact and countably compact are intrinsic properties of a topology, regardless of whether the space is considered in isolation or as a sub-space of another space. So we usually do not say "X is  countably compact (or compact) in Y" but simply "X is countably compact (or compact)."

Comment: @DanielWainfleet You're right. Thank you for pointing that out. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The continuous image of a countably compact space is countably compact (the proof is like the proof for compact spaces, just that one considers only countable open covers of the image), and a countably compact subspace of $\mathbb{R}$ is compact (since $\mathbb{R}$ is second countable, hence Lindelöf), thus

$$A_k = \{ f(k) : f \in M\}$$

is bounded for each $k \in K$. Therefore $F_k = \overline{A_k}$ is compact and by Tíkhonov's theorem,

$$\prod_{k \in K} F_k$$

is a compact subset of $\mathbb{R}^K$. Since $M \subset \prod\limits_{k\in K} F_k$, it follows that

$$\overline{M}^{\mathbb{R}^K} \subset \prod_{k\in K} F_k,$$

and as a closed subset of a compact set, it is itself compact.